# How to deserialize json file?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have json file, how can I deserialize this? As I understood json file had array which has 3 elements, but I didn't understand what is inside elements Id, Name, Driver and data inside Driver what is this (Driver) object?

```
[
   {
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"Renault Magnum",
      "Driver":{
         "Name":"John",
         "Surname":"Dou",
         "Age":35,
         "Experience":10
      },
      "State":"base"
   },
   {
      "Id":2,
      "Name":"Volvo FH12",
      "Driver":{
         "Name":"Jack",
         "Surname":"Dou",
         "Age":55,
         "Experience":30
      },
      "State":"base"
   },
   {
      "Id":3,
      "Name":"DAF XF",
      "Driver":{
         "Name":"Jane",
         "Surname":"Dou",
         "Age":45,
         "Experience":15
      },
      "State":"base"
   }
]
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Id appears to be an integer value, name, (driver) name, and surname seem to be strings, age and experience appear to be integers. State appears to be a string. Driver is a nested object.

Comment: I need deserialize this file

Comment: So make a couple of classes that represent the outer object and the driver object, then deserialize to a list of the outer object.

Comment: Try pasting JSON as classes in Visual Studio ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Paste Special*-Feature of Visual Studio to generate classes from a json. By applying this technique to the json above, you get the following classes as a result:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
}
```

This indicates that the answer to your question *what is inside elements Id, Name, Drivder and data inside Driver what is this (Driver) object?* is: Yes, it is an object.

I would recommend naming the elements in a useful way though ;-)